# HangFire Options

Tags: c#, cron, scheduling, hangfire

Does the HangFire takes care of the DayLight saving options.

Suppose I have a recurring job created at UTC Time ,which calls an api and which runs daily at 8 AM UTC which corresponds to 9 AM in the UK . Now tomorrow when the daylight saving takes place what happens to the job now.

Will it still trigger the job at 9 AM in the UK ?

Comment: It will still be triggered 8AM UTC, whatever that is in BST.

Comment: @fredrik, I understand that it triggers at 8 AM UTC still . What will be the time in UK correspondingly on the day light saving day . If it triggers at 10 AM instead of 9 AM , I will get unwanted results.